# Is it necessary to attach salary break up page along offer letter while forwarding to the HR of new employer?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, recruitment, human-resources, hiring

I waiting for my offer letter and the HR of that company is asking for my previous company offer letter. Do I have to submit the salary annexure also?

Comment: Can anyone advice me on this asap

Comment: At least your country is fairly important because here in north america you generally don't disclose your current salary at your new employer.

Comment: what do you mean by "annexture" is the base salary or salary and a break down of benefits

Comment: This sounds like India. Please tag your question yourself or confirm so someone else can tag it.

Comment: yes salary annexture means salary breakup and benefits included in that

Comment: @Swetha Even if this question is specific to India, it depends on the company. So you should ask them what they want and proceed from there.

Answer (score 3):

> Do i have submit salary annexture also?

**No.**

Your previous salary is really none of their business.  I would not share this information if I were in your position.

You are worth what the market will bear now, not your current salary plus a small percentage.  The salary *may* end up being the same, but a new positions salary should not be based on a previous positions pay.

**Note**: My answer holds true in most cases, in most locations.  However, in some countries this may be the norm. *Your mileage may vary*.